# Getting auto-complete to work correctly in scribble-mode

Tags: completion, auto-complete-mode, characters

I've been using Neil Van Dyke's [`scribble-mode`](http://www.neilvandyke.org/scribble-emacs/) for editing [Scribble](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/index.html) code in Emacs. I'm also using [`auto-complete`](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete) and [`ac-capf`](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-ac-capf) to get better completion in `scribble-mode`. However, I've been running into a problem wherein I can't get auto-completion directly after an `@` character in `scribble-mode` buffers. This is a problem because the `@` character [is an important part of Scribble's syntax.](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/reader.html) My current workaround is to type a keyword out and use a keybinding to auto-insert an `@` before the word. However, this is becoming quite tedious and I would like to have normal-style completion instead. A very weird part about this is that pressing `M-TAB` (which runs the `completion-at-point` function) displays completion candidates in the `*Completions*` buffer, even  after an `@` character, so I'm not sure why this isn't working with `auto-complete` / `ac-capf`. [Here's a screencast demonstrating my problem.](https://cl.ly/3O47001k1l0s/auto_complete_and_scribble_mode.mp4)

So, my question is how can I get auto-completion to work directly after an `@` character in `scribble-mode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a hacky solution / workaround to this problem. Instead of using [`ac-capf`](https://github.com/syohex/emacs-ac-capf) for completion, I used [`ac-company`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/buzztaiki/auto-complete/master/ac-company.el) to access the [`company-capf`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/company-mode/company-mode/master/company-capf.el) backend of [`company-mode`](http://company-mode.github.io). I put the following code in my init files to do this:

```
;; Feed company backends to auto-complete
(autoload 'ac-company-define-source "ac-company" nil nil 'macro)
(autoload 'ac-company-prefix "ac-company")
...
(ac-company-define-source ac-source-company-scribble company-capf)
(add-hook 'scribble-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                                 (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-company-scribble)
                                 (auto-complete-mode t)))
```

The reasons that this is hacky are that 1) it doesn't address the issue with `ac-capf` 2) this solution borks the auto-complete menu faces and 3) this solution causes an annoying error to appear in the minibuffer on completion and when cycling through completion candidates: `Error running timer ‘ac-quick-help’: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)`. Nonetheless, the error and messed up faces seem to be of no consequence and this solution appears to work fine. [Here's a screencast showing it in action.](https://cl.ly/3n3O3h0D1s1k/scribble_auto_complete_solution.mp4)